# Where does the 6502 store the low order byte after fetching for read instructions?

Tags: 6502

I am trying to get a mental model of how the 6502 operates. I am going off this image:
[image: this image]
However please suggest a better one if it helps understanding .

On [this website](http://www.atarihq.com/danb/files/64doc.txt) it describes how a read instruction occurs.

```
    Read instructions (LDA, LDX, LDY, EOR, AND, ORA, ADC, SBC, CMP, BIT,
                        LAX, NOP)

        #  address R/W description
       --- ------- --- ------------------------------------------
        1    PC     R  fetch opcode, increment PC
        2    PC     R  fetch low byte of address, increment PC
        3    PC     R  fetch high byte of address, increment PC
        4  address  R  read from effective address
```

My question is where do we store the low order byte after step 2 above? The obvious choice is the ABL however, would step 3 not overwrite this fetching the high byte of the address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [this blockdiagram](http://www.weihenstephan.org/%7Emichaste/pagetable/6502/6502.jpg), it matches the real layout of the 6502 a lot better. Also, have a look at [visual6502.org](http://visual6502.org/), you'll find more details about the chip to the tiniest detail, including a working simulator.

To definitely answer your question, you can just run the instructions in the simulator, and I'd have to do it myself, but I'd suspect the *adder hold register* (ADD) would hold the low byte address, as it can be directly output to ABL using the ADL bus.

Comment: Looking at Hansons diagram (Always use the [new version](https://www.witwright.com/DonPub/6502-Block-Diagram.pdf)) and Visual 6502 is always a good idea. Except, Visual6502 makes it a bit hard see this exact mechanic, as DL and A/B registers aren't shown, and expanded trace only shows ALU output (where it shows up). It's a tiny dance. During T2 the low byte gets stored in DL. In T3 it moves via ADL to ALU B-Input, zero gets added and put into ALU out (ADD) and outputted to ADL(again), where ABL picks it up during the next cycle. Nice little dance reusing existing real estate.

Comment: @Raffzahn that's what I would have expected, and it also sets the stage for the `$abs,X` and `$abs,Y` addressing modes, where you'd have to use the ALU anyway.